# Using deja-dup with GSuite or Onedrive

Tags: backup, deja-dup, online-storage

My university provides me with a Google Gsuite account with unlimited Google Drive space and a Microsoft Office 365 account with plenty of Onedrive space.

Is it possible to use one of these as storage location for my backups with deja-dup? After installing a few Python modules, I find Amazon S3, Google Cloud Storage (which apparently is not the same thing as Google Drive) and Rackspace as possible candidates, but not these ones.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way. Not necessarily a good way, but a way.

Set up (non-free) Google Drive client Insync.  Run your backups into a folder that is synced to Google Drive through Insync.

Comment: Thanks! This has the downside that I need a local copy of all the files in my backup set, though.

Comment: It's definitely not optimum.